# Odd compilation issue on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake

When I declare a `Mat` from opencv, the program still compiles without issues, but then does not produce any output when run. There are no warnings or errors during compilation. **However, this builds and runs correctly on Linux.**

Is this an issue with the compiler, or am I overlooking something extremely obvious?

***Note:*** In the build you can see that I am using the CLion IDE. I only use it for code insights and do all compilation and cmake tasks with the command line.

#### Includes

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
```

#### Working run

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    std::cout << "TEST\n";

    // This line is commented out!
    // Mat object;

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "There was an issue!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    /* Commented out code */
    return 0;
}
```

> C:\Path\To\Project\build> cmake --build . --config Release
>    Wow! Your code is amazing and compiled without any issues!
>   C:\Path\To\Project\build> Release\test.exe
>   TEST
>   There was an issue!

#### Problem run

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    std::cout << "TEST\n";

    // All I did was remove the comment on this line!
    Mat object;

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "There was an issue!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    /* Commented out code */
    return 0;
}
```

> C:\Path\To\Project\build> cmake --build . --config Release
>    Wow! Your code is amazing and compiled without any issues!
>   C:\Path\To\Project\build> Release\test.exe
>   
>   C:\Path\To\Project\build> *exited without output*

#### Build

```
C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build>cmake --build . --config Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 1/14/2019 9:54:14 PM.
Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
All outputs are up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\Test.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
Creating "Test.dir\Release\Test.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
All outputs are up-to-date.
ClCompile:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\include" /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /
D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"Test.dir\Release\\" /Fd"Test.dir\Release\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp
        main.cpp
        Link:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\Release\Test.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.
0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_dnn401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_gapi401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_ml401.lib" "
C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_objdetect401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_photo401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\buil
        d\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_stitching401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_video401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_calib3d401.lib" "C:\Users\
  home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_features2d401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_flann401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\instal
        l\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_highgui401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_videoio401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_imgcodecs401.lib" "C:\Users\home
\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_imgproc401.lib" "C:\Users\home\Documents\opencv-4.0.1\opencv-4.0.1\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_core401.lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut
32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"C:/Users/home/CLionProjects/untitled/build/Release/Test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/home
/CLionProjects/untitled/build/Release/Test.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 Test.dir\Release\main.obj
Test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\Release\Test.exe
        FinalizeBuildStatus:
Deleting file "Test.dir\Release\Test.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
Touching "Test.dir\Release\Test.tlog\Test.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\Test.vcxproj" (default targets).

InitializeBuildStatus:
Creating "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
All outputs are up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
Deleting file "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
Touching "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\ALL_BUILD.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\home\CLionProjects\untitled\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.64
```

### Is there an issue with the library I am using when building on Windows? Is my compiler silently failing? Did I make a simple mistake?

Comment: What if you go into Release directory and then run the command?

Comment: Exact same result.

Comment: Ok, sometimes if libraries are not found it just silently won’t run but seems that’s not the case here...

Comment: Maybe your program does not find the library at _runtime_. Check your compiler library search directory.

Comment: How would I verify if it is found at runtime? It already took me an hour to get cmake to stop complaining about invalid links.

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: It looks like OpenCV library, which you use on Windows, is somehow **incompatible** with VisualStudio. "It already took me an hour to get cmake to stop complaining about invalid links." - Well, this could be a very reason of the problem. Show your `CMakeLists.txt` - exactly it is responsible for link the program with a proper library.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, but without the extra modules and python. I also changed the target to `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` and used the latest opencv version. The makefile is the roughly same though. https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/

Comment: Which generator would you suggest for using on windows with cmake? I also have WSL installed if that makes a difference.